# How To Solve React Hydration Error in Next

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I keep getting an error saying "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

I have no idea what is causing the error so I was hoping someone else may know what is wrong. I think I narrowed down where the error is happening and posted the code below of where I think it breaks. If any more code is needed let me know.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.css";
import Coin from "../Coin/Coin";

type CoinListProps = {
  coins: any;
};

const CoinList = ({ coins }: CoinListProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(coins);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.coinList}>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Coin</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>24h</th>
        </tr>
        {coins.map((coin: any, index: any) => (
          <Coin key={index} coin={coin} />
        ))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CoinList;
```

Comment: what will coin compoent will return ? is it table rows ?

Comment: This code just by itself wouldn't trigger the hydration error. Can you show us the code for `Coin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably missed `tbody` in `table`. This will cause an error in **NextJS**. Try:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Coin</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>24h</th>
        </tr>
        {coins.map((coin: any, index: any) => (
            <Coin key={index} coin={coin} />
        ))}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Never knew about tbody and thead being a thing, probably should've paid better attention to my HTML classes lol

Answer (score 5):

If you want to suppress a hydration warning on a given component, you can pass the `suppressHydrationWarning` prop to it.

This signals to `React` that the component's content *may* be different once the page is re-rendered on the client-side and to ignore the error.

```
<Coin key={index} coin={coin} suppressHydrationWarning />
```

See [Suppress Hydration Warning (React Docs)](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#suppresshydrationwarning):

> If you set suppressHydrationWarning to true, React will not warn you about mismatches in the attributes and the content of that element. It only works one level deep, and is intended to be used as an escape hatch. Don’t overuse it. You can read more about hydration in the ReactDOM.hydrateRoot() documentation.